# Extract name and surname from string in c#

Tags: c#, string, email

I need extract the **name** and **surname** from a **email string**.

In the database I have two type of address email working :

> name.surname@xxxx.eu

Or

> name.surname@xxxx.com

And I have tried this code :

```
    string Email1 = Email.ToString().ToUpper().Replace("@", "");
    if (Email1.Contains("XXXX.COM"))
    {
        Response.Write(Email1.ToString().Replace(".", " ").ToUpper().Remove(Email1.Length - 8, 8) + "<br />");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write(Email1.ToString().Replace(".", " ").ToUpper().Remove(Email1.Length - 7, 7) + "<br />");
    }
```

This code not working for only these addresses emails :

> VINCENT.NAPOLITAIN@XXXX.EU

because the return is :

> VINCENT NAPOLITAINX

Not working for :

> MARK.CHAIN@XXXX.COM

because the return is :

> MARK CHAINX

Not working for :

> NICODEMUS.ANGELICUM@XXXX.EU

because the return is :

> NICODEMUS ANGELICUMX

How to do resolve this?

Please help me, thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried - cough - debugging it? Setting a breakpoint, Going through a test case line by line. This is baseline programmer behavior - rather learn it sooner than later. It is quite obvious your string manipulation is off - likely the offsets are wrong. The X at the end indicates that you copy one character too much - so why do you not copy one less?

Comment: @TomTom thank you I have tried with breakpoint on debug for this I noticed error

Comment: What happens with a mail like `mary.jean.napolitain@xxxx.eu`? Or `peter.smith.2@xxx.eu`? (because *Peter Smith* is such a frequent name that you have to use additional characters)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks but on the db I have only `name.surname@xxxx.eu` or `xxxx.com`

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq Actually I bet - this either is homework, or a super irrelevant project, or your test data is BROKEN. Because yes, some names are so common the pattern HAS to be broken. Wernfried is correct - you do not handle double names (famous Eva Maria Brandauer - not only a man, but yes, that is a double name at the front) but also have an issue with very common names. Check the specs. Not what is written - this should be clarified.

Comment: Hint: stripping off `@` and everything following it (from any email address) is trivial without hard coding lengths (`str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("@"))`, and would lead to far cleaner code. (Hard coding string lengths is almost certainly your problem here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplistic approach (based on the requirements that you specified, which seem to be a bit strange):

```
var test = "name.surname@xxxx.eu";
var name = test.Substring(0, test.IndexOf('@')).Replace(".", " ");
```

Might want to add exception handling, of course.

Answer (score 5):

why don't you split your address by the both seperator characters `@` and `.`

```
string email = "VINCENT.NAPOLITAIN@XXXX.EU"; 
string[] result = email.Split('.', '@').ToArray();
string firstname = result[0];
string lastname = result[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use String.split():

```
string email = "VINCENT.NAPOLITAIN@XXXX.EU"; 
string names = email.Split('@')[0];
string name = "";
string surname = "";
if (names.Contains('.'))
{
    var nameSurname = names.Split('.');
    name = nameSurname[0]; //
    surname = nameSurname[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can use [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) Pattern:**

```
(.+)\.(.+)(?=\@)
```

**Explanation:**

```
 (.+)   - Matches any character in a group 
 \.     - Matches (.) dot 
 (?=\@) - Exclude @ character
```

**Code:**

```
var match = Regex.Match(email, pattern);
var name = match.Groups[1].Value;
var surname = match.Groups[2].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to find the index of the `.` and the index of the `@` and do substrings on that:

```
string email = "aa.bb@cc.dd";

int periodIndex = email.IndexOf('.');
int atIndex = email.IndexOf('@');

string firstName = email.Substring(0, periodIndex);
string lastName = email.Substring(periodIndex + 1, atIndex - periodIndex - 1);
```

An easier way is to use a regular expression that cuts out the names.

This one will do:

```
(.*?)\.(.*?)@(.*)
```

The first capture is the first name, the second capture is the last name.

Comment: On, come on. As much as I like regex - this programmer has problems counting (as he copies one char too long). And now you want him to learn REGEX? That is challenging for quite some people.

Comment: Okay. Fixed that @TomTom. Added a regular way to extract them too.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `split` in order to do it:

```
var nameDOTsurname = Email1.Split('@'); // This would leave in nameDOTsurname[0] the name.surname and in nameDOTsurname[1] the XXX.whatever
var name = nameDOTsurname[0].Split('.')[0];
var surname = nameDOTsurname[0].Split('.')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work if your email address format sticks to `firstname.secondname@wherever...`
here is the code that works for you...

```
string e = "VINCENT.NAPOLITAIN@XXXX.EU"; 
string firstname = e.Substring(0, e.IndexOf("."));
string secondname = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(".")+1, s.IndexOf("@")-s.IndexOf(".")-1);
```

It works for all your emails